# Android list items replace with new items

Tags: listview, android-fragments, listviewitem

I have a fragment in tablayout, l have list view to display items, when click onItemClick, **I want to replace new items with old items and when press back button, old items show**, like parent and child, i use fragmenttransaction.replace, but I don't how?

Comment: It shouldn't matter how your list adapter is filled. You need to buffer a copy if you want two different versions if it. You could store where the item is gotten from the net or just a boolean as to whether it's the proper version or the alternative version, but you need to store that data, use that data to back your adapter and revert to the original when you hit back.

Answer (score 0):

This depends a bit more on what you are exactly doing with that. The big point is that list views do not have the actual objects just views of them backed by the adapter. When you click on the item you need to modify the datastructure you have backing the list view to display the alternative view. Then notify the adapter that the items have changed.

Then equally when you press the back button you catch that onBackPressed and use it to restore all the views to the original version and again notify the adapter that the items have changed.

Codewise at the most simple:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    static final String blah = "Blah";
    static final String touched = "Touched!";
    static final int LIMIT = 1000;
    BaseAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView v = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        for (int i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++) {
            items.add(blah);
        }
        adapter = new BaseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return items.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int i) {
                return items.get(i);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int i) {
                return i;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
                TextView tv;
                if (view != null) {
                    tv = (TextView)view;
                }
                else {
                    tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Integer value = (Integer)view.getTag();
                            items.set(value, touched);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                }
                tv.setTag(i);
                tv.setText(items.get(i));
                return tv;
            }
        };
        v.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        boolean flag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++) {
            if (!blah.equals(items.get(i))) {
                flag = true;
                items.set(i,blah);
            }

        }
        if (flag) adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        else super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, and another question, don't need fragmentTransaction.replace and addBack by fragment stack?

Comment: New questions should be asked in new question. And I don't really understand your question.

Comment: Also if this answered your question it's proper to accept the answer. If it didn't update your question to properly explain in better detail what you are asking.

Comment: I get products category from net and display in list view, when click on item, display child, click on item, display child it until finish category selected and display advertising, now click back press button to display parent, parent until first item, how to doing?

Comment: You could do that with multiple intents. Or with it on one screen or whatnot. Generally it sounds like what you want is just to have each thing you click launch another activity that simply views the data on that. There's a bunch of different ways to do that. But, namely it's just grab the item, get the other data on it and display that data anyway you'd like. That's just basically clicking.